# Trying to write a custom template tag in Django that finds a phone number in text and converts it to a link

Tags: django, django-templates, wagtail

I want to convert this string `tel:123-456-7890.1234` to a `a` link in html. The final output would be `<a href="tel:1234567890,1234">123-456-7890 ext 1234</a>`

I'm not great with Regex and I'm REALLY close, but I need some help. I know that I'm not all the way there with the regex and output. How do I change what I have to make it work?

```
import re

@register.filter(name='phonify')
@stringfilter
def phonify(val):
    """
    Pass the string 'tel:1234' to the filter and the right tel link is returned.
    """
    # find every instance of 'tel' and then get the number after it
    for tel in re.findall(r'tel:(\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{4})\D*(\d*)', val):
        # format the tag for each instance of tel
        tag = '<a href="tel:{}">{}</a>'.format(tel, tel)
        # replace the tel instance with the new formatted html
        val = val.replace('tel:{}'.format(tel), tag)
    # return the new output to the template context
    return val
```

I added the wagtail tag as I've seen other solutions for this in Wagtail and is something needed for Wagtail, so this might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` to perform a find and replace:

```
import re

@register.filter(name='phonify')
@stringfilter
def phonify(val):
    tel_rgx = r'tel:(\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{4}\D*\d*)'
    return re.sub(tel_rgx, r'<a href="tel:\1">\1</a>', val)
```

Note however that in your template, you will need to mark the result as "safe", otherwise it will replace `<` with `&lt;` etc and thus render `<a href=` as *text*.

You can mark the string as safe in your template fiter as well:

```
import re
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

@register.filter(name='phonify')
@stringfilter
def phonify(val):
    tel_rgx = r'tel:(\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{3}\D{0,3}\d{4}\D*\d*)'
    return mark_safe(re.sub(tel_rgx, r'<a href="tel:\1">\1</a>', val))
```

Regardless how you do this, it will however mark all items as safe, even tags, etc. that are part of the original string, and thus should be escaped. Therefore, I'm not sure that this is a good idea.